# Postman POST request working but cURL output failing

Tags: bash, curl, post, request, postman

Hi, I have used postman to make a successful (response code 200) POST request, however the cURL code that it postman provides in its "code" section is failing:

[image: postman 200]

This code is generating a 419 error ("unknown error"):

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://screenpehots' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=d992d1c6e2c91c59803d953a83ad3dcee1589477309; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlZOeGpmTVBZYzJnaFpIVXZudGtOM1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaXJnY2JMaXptTGNCb3U3bVgrUk9xeTJtV3RwSDdwSkN0M1BNSWpNa0tjK1RkUGtiKzlLdG8wbmp0WjZoTmZybyIsIm1hYyI6ImMxYjQyZjk5MTM2NDZmOTNhMGZjZjcyNjhjMTYyNWQ4OTQ4NzY2OWIyMjg1MjI5Mzk0OWZhYjQ2Y2ZhZGM1NjgifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImtZdngwK3VXdjFHdjBVcmd3RG1LbGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiN2NaWmJyYStmV3FJMU9LODdjcUZWTGdqV2dtQnBJbTdMaTRNbUZPTkdTXC9rSEVQTGc5dWlwOWZFMVhlTmNiQkEiLCJtYWMiOiIwZGIwMGEzYjA5ZDQ5YWFiMDE3ODJkMjdmZTg5MjUzNzQwZTAwMzUxODRhNTdhYzFiMmQ0MmViYWJlMzM5NDljIn0%3D' --data-urlencode '_token=6c8nSDhYEWVgx8O9pR0tKv70jTcl5zmmyLu3fMoO' --data-urlencode 'device=iphone' --data-urlencode 'url=http://www.amazon.com'
```

And this code generates a 405 ("method not allowed"):

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://screenpeek.io/shots' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Cookie: __cfduid=d992d1c6e2c91c59803d953a83ad3dcee1589477309; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjJCTGdcL0VTaEk1dCtcL1Z2ZXp0Zng5UT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJOQzdHWFl2UlhcL3JISDNpdDdDMEpGZFVVczROOVVqT0U1cVFrN3RtK2ROdUlFV1U2cEl4MnRTZndtT2hENk5ONCIsIm1hYyI6IjJlNmIxZTQ2ZDE5NzA1OTg1NDEyNGYyNjdiOTEyMzdjM2Y0ZGZmMGY1OTMxMGI4OTVmMTk1ZTk1NjZmZWUzOGQifQ%3D%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImI4U1lRamFOYnZqR0ZUU1dlZG1VeFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaExFSHJ2VjJRNnBPc2RWeWhVOWxMYmd1R2lscVpDdTdOMHhpY3ozNDFYZlFGSzlyZkV4VFhNUlB0aGpCbDFmdyIsIm1hYyI6ImFlNGM4M2Y4ZTBjMGQ3YWQ4MWIwZmQxMTAyNzcxMGFkNTU1ZjRkYTUwYWQ0YmQyNWFkNjgwZTQzY2I3MjMxNDEifQ%3D%3D' \
--data-raw '{
    "_token": "6c8nSDhYEWVgx8O9pR0tKv70jTcl5zmmyLu3fMoO",
    "device": "iphone",
    "url": "http://www.amazon.com"
}'
```

I have attempted to debug the issue but still haven't managed to work out the cause...

```
== Info: TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
=> Send SSL data, 52 bytes (0x34)
0000: ...0<.\.@?......D:.a...Tsp...h.%.P.MZP...{..s..*....
== Info: SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
== Info: ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
== Info: Server certificate:
== Info:  subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=sni.cloudflaressl.com
== Info:  start date: Feb  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT
== Info:  expire date: Oct  9 12:00:00 2020 GMT
== Info:  subjectAltName: host "screenpeek.io" matched cert's "screenpeek.io"
== Info:  issuer: C=US; ST=CA; L=San Francisco; O=CloudFlare, Inc.; CN=CloudFlare Inc ECC CA-2
== Info:  SSL certificate verify ok.
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: ....Q
=> Send SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
=> Send header, 739 bytes (0x2e3)
0000: POST /shots HTTP/1.1
0016: Host: screenpeek.io
002b: User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
0044: Accept: */*
0051: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
0082: Cookie: __cfduid=d992d1c6e2c91c59803d953a83ad3dcee1589477309; XS
00c2: RF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlZOeGpmTVBZYzJnaFpIVXZudGtOM1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjo
0102: iaXJnY2JMaXptTGNCb3U3bVgrUk9xeTJtV3RwSDdwSkN0M1BNSWpNa0tjK1RkUGt
0142: iKzlLdG8wbmp0WjZoTmZybyIsIm1hYyI6ImMxYjQyZjk5MTM2NDZmOTNhMGZjZjc
0182: yNjhjMTYyNWQ4OTQ4NzY2OWIyMjg1MjI5Mzk0OWZhYjQ2Y2ZhZGM1NjgifQ%3D%3
01c2: D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImtZdngwK3VXdjFHdjBVcmd3RG1LbGc9PSIsI
0202: nZhbHVlIjoiN2NaWmJyYStmV3FJMU9LODdjcUZWTGdqV2dtQnBJbTdMaTRNbUZPT
0242: kdTXC9rSEVQTGc5dWlwOWZFMVhlTmNiQkEiLCJtYWMiOiIwZGIwMGEzYjA5ZDQ5Y
0282: WFiMDE3ODJkMjdmZTg5MjUzNzQwZTAwMzUxODRhNTdhYzFiMmQ0MmViYWJlMzM5N
02c2: DljIn0%3D
02cd: Content-Length: 93
02e1: 
=> Send data, 93 bytes (0x5d)
0000: _token=6c8nSDhYEWVgx8O9pR0tKv70jTcl5zmmyLu3fMoO&device=iphone&ur
0040: l=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com
== Info: upload completely sent off: 93 out of 93 bytes
<= Recv SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: .....
<= Recv SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
== Info: TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
<= Recv SSL data, 230 bytes (0xe6)
0000: .......  .\H....8-......@m.H........W.oC.|...@..eC`>g..'.!..C.{K
0040: .Mc..L.4 .9=....!...e......m.L.&7.v.xN(..k........*.I..|.y.oW..
0080: a..rqHW(w.(.RR{U...$..T...'..2*.4.h.R.AENM..n...%q....X.(g......
00c0: 2ZS.j...Y^.L.R.e._....e.......R.......
== Info: TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
<= Recv SSL data, 230 bytes (0xe6)
0000: ....... ;5.;....8-......@m.H....w.r.8..!../.....X.......&.......
0040: urh.... .,.x$\6Q....7....4?r....l.'.v,..|...o.+.;..0....>L.....9
0080: .6..^....X.~.i......:.......VV|.....P.......6,C....&x.p.*....R..
00c0: ..[8.h4.o.^.R;....v...ZT...7X..O......
== Info: old SSL session ID is stale, removing
<= Recv SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: ....j
<= Recv SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
== Info: Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
<= Recv header, 20 bytes (0x14)
0000: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 18:16:08 GMT
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: keep-alive
<= Recv header, 34 bytes (0x22)
0000: Cache-Control: no-cache, private
<= Recv header, 46 bytes (0x2e)
0000: Location: https://screenpeek.io/shots/qkjrm1
<= Recv header, 334 bytes (0x14e)
0000: Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlZoRVE3aVZXRGtwSkpSOUJSMFhwMUE9P
0040: SIsInZhbHVlIjoiaW1CVUIyakN4b0R2Y0MyMWRQb2xqRGI3c083ZVFWZmdiZEU0d
0080: k9CdmkrcFBXdkhoSEs4UytuTUxkV3k0Q1I1UCIsIm1hYyI6IjUwNzBmYmY0OWFlN
00c0: DJiNTM1ZmM3NDlhODUxZTQwMTZiMGRiMjNjNmY1NWU5NGQzZWQwNzcwYmQyODVmY
0100: WQ0NzMifQ%3D%3D; expires=Thu, 14-May-2020 20:16:08 GMT; Max-Age=
0140: 7200; path=/
<= Recv header, 29 bytes (0x1d)
0000: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
<= Recv header, 33 bytes (0x21)
0000: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
<= Recv header, 33 bytes (0x21)
0000: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
<= Recv header, 349 bytes (0x15d)
0000: set-cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InZBR3ZyK3VBRWtPWkhZR0huOUQx
0040: QlE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVXFMaUlyM3lMeGNrVzgrUHl0YjZYSlYwM0E1TlJyYlJw
0080: Yll2R3F6aGdKQnFnNFFZcE5ZK1M2QVdxbXdUcng3MyIsIm1hYyI6IjcwNmQzNjEx
00c0: ZTg3MzZmOWNhM2M4YjFkODVhMjVjYjYzMTc2N2QyZTllMzczZDIxMzIwZWM2ZThj
0100: YzFiZWM5NTQifQ%3D%3D; expires=Thu, 14-May-2020 20:16:08 GMT; Max
0140: -Age=7200; path=/; httponly
<= Recv header, 100 bytes (0x64)
0000: Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudf
0040: lare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
<= Recv header, 20 bytes (0x14)
0000: Server: cloudflare
<= Recv header, 30 bytes (0x1e)
0000: CF-RAY: 59369bcb4cfbe664-LHR
<= Recv header, 49 bytes (0x31)
0000: cf-request-id: 02b5ffb30d0000e664ac8a1200000001
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
== Info: Ignoring the response-body
<= Recv data, 135 bytes (0x87)
0000: 17c
0005: <!DOCTYPE html>.<html>.    <head>.        <meta charset="UTF-8" 
0045: />.        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://scr
0085: ee
<= Recv SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: .....
<= Recv SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
<= Recv data, 252 bytes (0xfc)
0000: npeek.io/shots/qkjrm1" />..        <title>Redirecting to https:/
0040: /screenpeek.io/shots/qkjrm1</title>.    </head>.    <body>.     
0080:    Redirecting to <a href="https://screenpeek.io/shots/qkjrm1">h
00c0: ttps://screenpeek.io/shots/qkjrm1</a>..    </body>.</html>
<= Recv SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: .....
<= Recv SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
<= Recv data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: 0
0003: 
== Info: Connection #0 to host screenpeek.io left intact
== Info: Issue another request to this URL: 'https://screenpeek.io/shots/qkjrm1'
== Info: Switch from POST to GET
== Info: Found bundle for host screenpeek.io: 0x7f8d17c16740 [serially]
== Info: Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host screenpeek.io
== Info: Connected to screenpeek.io (104.24.101.9) port 443 (#0)
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: .....
=> Send SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
=> Send header, 726 bytes (0x2d6)
0000: POST /shots/qkjrm1 HTTP/1.1
001d: Host: screenpeek.io
0032: User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
004b: Accept: */*
0058: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
0089: Cookie: __cfduid=d992d1c6e2c91c59803d953a83ad3dcee1589477309; XS
00c9: RF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlZOeGpmTVBZYzJnaFpIVXZudGtOM1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjo
0109: iaXJnY2JMaXptTGNCb3U3bVgrUk9xeTJtV3RwSDdwSkN0M1BNSWpNa0tjK1RkUGt
0149: iKzlLdG8wbmp0WjZoTmZybyIsIm1hYyI6ImMxYjQyZjk5MTM2NDZmOTNhMGZjZjc
0189: yNjhjMTYyNWQ4OTQ4NzY2OWIyMjg1MjI5Mzk0OWZhYjQ2Y2ZhZGM1NjgifQ%3D%3
01c9: D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImtZdngwK3VXdjFHdjBVcmd3RG1LbGc9PSIsI
0209: nZhbHVlIjoiN2NaWmJyYStmV3FJMU9LODdjcUZWTGdqV2dtQnBJbTdMaTRNbUZPT
0249: kdTXC9rSEVQTGc5dWlwOWZFMVhlTmNiQkEiLCJtYWMiOiIwZGIwMGEzYjA5ZDQ5Y
0289: WFiMDE3ODJkMjdmZTg5MjUzNzQwZTAwMzUxODRhNTdhYzFiMmQ0MmViYWJlMzM5N
02c9: DljIn0%3D
02d4: 
<= Recv SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: ....G
<= Recv SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
== Info: Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
<= Recv header, 33 bytes (0x21)
0000: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 18:16:08 GMT
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: keep-alive
<= Recv header, 18 bytes (0x12)
0000: allow: GET, HEAD
<= Recv header, 34 bytes (0x22)
0000: Cache-Control: no-cache, private
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
<= Recv header, 100 bytes (0x64)
0000: Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudf
0040: lare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
<= Recv header, 20 bytes (0x14)
0000: Server: cloudflare
<= Recv header, 30 bytes (0x1e)
0000: CF-RAY: 59369bcc4f39e664-LHR
<= Recv header, 49 bytes (0x31)
0000: cf-request-id: 02b5ffb3b10000e664ac8a7200000001
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 637 bytes (0x27d)
0000: 276
0005: <!DOCTYPE html>.<html>.    <head>.        <meta charset="UTF-8" 
0045: />.        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />.   
0085:      <style>                body { background-color: #fff; color
00c5: : #222; font: 16px/1.5 -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe
0105:  UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; }.
0145:                 .container { margin: 30px; max-width: 600px; }. 
0185:                h1 { color: #dc3545; font-size: 24px; }</style>. 
01c5:    </head>.    <body>.                        <div class="contai
0205: ner">.                    <h1>Whoops, looks like something went 
0245: wrong.</h1>.                </div>.    </body>.</html>
<= Recv SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: .....
<= Recv SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
<= Recv data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: 0
0003: 
== Info: Connection #0 to host screenpeek.io left intactz
```